# Open source tool for managing social media accounts

Tags: gratis, open-source, web-apps, social-networks

Is there any open source tool / app for managing social media accounts?

I am running a startup. I would like to manage all the social media accounts like Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn and Google Plus in one place.

I searched, but I end up getting only paid tools.

Comment: To clarify: are you only looking for *free* open source tools?

Comment: @freginold: OP says they found only "paid tools", so I assume they are looking for gratis tools (I added the tag).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple open source tools that can manage social media accounts for you. Here are two:

---

### Socioboard

[Socioboard](https://socioboard.org/) offers an open source version and a commercial version. It supports Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Instagram (but not Google Plus). From the website:

> Socioboard Core is an open source social media management, analytics and reporting platform. It supports nine social media networks. Using Socioboard Core you can monitor and manage multiple social media accounts and create useful reports and take business decisions based on them. Socioboard Core is available as a web app and mobile apps on iOS and Android. Its completely open source and fully customizable and extensible in the form of plugins. It has a commercial SAAS version at – www.socioboard.com and open source version at – www.socioboard.org

---

### CampaignChain

[CampaignChain](https://www.campaignchain.com/) is free, open source software that can help manage accounts for Facebook, Twitter, Google Analytics, LinkedIn, and more.

---

In addition, below are links to two blog posts that list several alternatives. The first link also includes a chart comparing some of the programs.

- [The Top 7 Free Social Media Management Software](https://blog.capterra.com/top-free-social-media-management-software/) (from Capterra)
- [Top 42 Free Social Media Management, Social Media Analytics and Social Publishing Software](https://www.predictiveanalyticstoday.com/top-free-social-media-analytics-software/) (from Predictive Analytics Today)

---

*Disclaimer*: I have not used or tested any of these apps.